# Test for empty jQuery selection result

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I do

```
var s = $('#something');
```

and next I want to test if jQuery found #something, i.e. I want to test if `s` is empty.

I could use my trusty `isempty()` on it:

```
function isempty(o) {
    for ( var i in o )
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Or since jQuery objects are arrays, I suppose I could test `s.length`.

But neither seem quite in the idiom of jQuery, not very jQueryesque. What do you suggest?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299802/how-do-you-check-if-a-selector-exists-in-jquery

Comment: inkedmn, yes, similar question but I didn't see the `.size()` answer there, which I rather like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect if a selector returns null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920236/how-can-i-detect-if-a-selector-returns-null)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Use the s.length property.

```
if(s.length == 0) {
    ...
}
```

[edit] size() deprecated in jquery 1.8
http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 6):

```
if($("#something").length > 0 ){
     // Element found
}
else{
    // No element found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An even more jQueryesque solution for me is:

```
jQuery.fn.isEmpty = function(fun){ if (this.length === 0) { fun(); } return this; };
```

This lets me write in typical fashion:

```
$("#sel").fadeOut(500,afterFade).isEmpty(insteadOfFade);
```