# My html page crashes on ctrl+c

Tags: javascript, browser, copy, ctrl

I have a *very simple* html page that crashes when I <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. But:

- select and right click copy works fine.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> works fine too.

The problem persists on Chrome 49, Firefox 43 & IE 11.

- IE offers an explanation: "localhost is not responding due to a long running script".
- Chrome the usual: "Aw Snap! Something went wrong".
- Firefox simply stops responding.

Because of the above I think it's safe to rule out HTML/CSS problems, as well as browser issues. If it weren't for that IE message, I would also rule out JS problems.

I don't understand how <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> causes a script to run (if I am to trust IE), and I don't know how to find that script. This seems to be a **tab-specific issue** as all 3 browsers continue to work fine on the other tabs, while the problematic one has stopped responding.

Anyone else had this problem?

I'm running windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your page runs some script. Maybe one of them has unending loop started on push <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: it was a typical infinite loop afterall. I don't know yet why it is caused only by `ctrl + c` and not by `ctrl + v` though.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles upon the same problem >>>

I found the "long running script". (IE saves the day, yay!)

The problem was a typical infinite loop caused by **jQuery returning an empty set `[]`** when I was checking for **null** or **'undefined'** to end my loop.

check [this stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649346/test-for-empty-jquery-selection-result) for more.