# Click Event Listner on Hashchange page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any specific way for click event handlers for hash-change pages? For example, suppose I have a page ​**abc.com​**. Clicking on a specific tab gives us **abc.com#/tab1**, a hashed page. On the hashed page, I want to add click event on, say, *Save*​ button.

My implementation assumes that the elements are all child nodes of *body* and hence using event-delegation. However, the same does not work as desired.

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
    console.log(window.location.hash);
    $( "body" ).on( "click", "button", function( event ) {
      if (window.location.hash === "#/tab1")
        console.log("testing success");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, congrats on asking your first Stackoverflow question :) welcome! I made a few edits. Most were trivial spacing edits to the text, but I also changed your code block to be formatted by leading with 4 spaces. The back-tick is generally used when you want to have a bit of code inline like `this for example`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [answer of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change), you can use jQuery approach for this one:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {

  console.log(window.location.hash);

    saveButton = $('#saveBtn:not(.bound)');
    if (saveButton != undefined) {
        saveButton.addClass('bound').click(function(){
            if (window.location.hash == '#/tab1') {
                console.log('testing success!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Checking for `.bound` class ensures that the click event is bound only once to the saveButton. ([Source here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361465/how-to-check-if-click-event-is-already-bound-jquery#answer-6930078))

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its partially working. The issue is, initially when I click on the _Save_ button its not working. However, when I revisit the page again, its working. My current implementation uses .ready() to check if the DOM contents are loaded or not, but still its not working. The code is provided in the next comment.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {

        button = $("div.class button");
        console.log(button);
        console.log($("div.class button").length);
        
        if (button !== undefined) {
            $("div.class button").click(function() {
                if (window.location.hash == '#/tab-1') {
                    console.log('testing success new 2!');
                }
            });
        }
    }); `

Comment: `div.class button` refers to a <button> inside a <div> with class=“class”, which I doubt you have. Don’t use `button !== undefined` to check for existence; use `button.length !== 0` instead, as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920236/how-can-i-detect-if-a-selector-returns-null). The button will never have an `undefined` value as long as it’s assigned from a jQuery selector method, even if the selector you specified is non-existing.

Comment: Instead of "div.class button", can you try using just "button", or specifically, the id of your _Save_ button?